# Ecci meaning and usage examples

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I'm writing a project whose name nicely acronyms to "ecci". Google translate says "ecci" is Italian for "energized", but there's no example available. Additionally, I've found eccì means achoo :)

Is the translation correct and appropriate? Does this word work out of context, i. e. as a standalone term? Can someone give a couple of usage examples if its correct?

Comment: That's not an Italian word. Can you provide the context where you found it?

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi: I seem to understand that the OP never actually found this word anywhere: he came up with it as an acronym, and then looked it up in Google Translate to see if it meant something in some language.

Comment: Wops, I read it from my phone. My bad, I missed that.

Comment: I agree with @laika that google translate is wrong, so therefore sneeze would be the correct translation of ecci.

Answer (score 9):

Google Translate is wrong in this case, probably is associating "ecci" to "eccitato", which means "excited" or "energized".

"Eccì" can be recognized as a sneeze onomatopea, but I think "etciù" is more common.

Comment: L'uso onomatopeico è riportato dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ecci/).

Comment: @IgorR:  You can find [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ecci/) an example of this onomatopeic use: *un fragoroso eccì*, which means a thunderous sneeze.